# How to avoid duplicate code that use Apex tag?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have one `<apex:repeat>` loop duplicated for styling reasons in the HTML/CSS page.

Is there a way to avoid the duplication of code ? I tried to call a JS function to replace the inner HTML of an added div, but it did not work.

Is there another to do it ?

Comment: I think you could create [custom component](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.pages_custom_components.htm&type=5), include all the code you need, and place the component in many places as needed.